# No access to selected images via image picker plugin in iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, plugins, ionic-native

I wrote a code which selects an image from the gallery and both shows it locally as an tag and uploads its base64 form to the server.

It works totally fine in android platform but there are issues in iOS.

There are two things:

1- I get the path which is something like

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/[some string]/tmp/[a name].jpg
```

2- and tags are already configured to allow "file"s

I appreciate any helpful guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `cordova-plugin-image-picker` you can set the option `outputType: 1`. This will return image in base64 format.

From [plugin](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/ImagePicker) repository:

```
options = {
    // Android only. Max images to be selected, defaults to 15. If this is set to 1, upon
    // selection of a single image, the plugin will return it.
    maximumImagesCount: int,

    // max width and height to allow the images to be.  Will keep aspect
    // ratio no matter what.  So if both are 800, the returned image
    // will be at most 800 pixels wide and 800 pixels tall.  If the width is
    // 800 and height 0 the image will be 800 pixels wide if the source
    // is at least that wide.
    width: int,
    height: int,

    // quality of resized image, defaults to 100
    quality: int (0-100),

    // output type, defaults to FILE_URIs.
    // available options are 
    // window.imagePicker.OutputType.FILE_URI (0) or 
    // window.imagePicker.OutputType.BASE64_STRING (1)
    outputType: int
};
```

Remember to add `data:image/jpeg;base64,` before the returned string. 
Then, for example:

```
this.imagePicker.getPictures({ 
    maximumImagesCount: 1, 
    width: 800, 
    height: 800, 
    quality: 70, 
    outputType: 1 }) //base64 output
.then((results) => {
    return 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+results[0]; 
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try but obviously it's not still working for using as an image tag src atr. any ideas?

Comment: Use [src]="img" instead of src="{{ img }}". Have you tried to log results?

Comment: That didn't make any difference but the "outputType: 1" gave me a cool base64 string which could be sent to the server. So i'm sure cordova doesn't have access to native storage. I don't know how to grant it.

Comment: It's possible to access to native storage by this plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/ but for image picking i prefer base64

Comment: I gave up with the preview feature. Anyway, Thanks :)